# In TensorFlow, how to extract compute_gradient() gradients to numpy?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent

**Goal:**

I am trying to test a training algorithm using Tensorflow and numpy. I would like to extract the gradients to numpy, manipulate them, then apply them to Tensorflow's variables.

I know this approach is inefficient. I am doing this because my implementation in numpy is working, and I am trying to figure out how to manipulate the gradients in Tensorflow first.

**What I Have**

Here is a summary of what I have.

```py
# Extract Gradients and Values
tgv = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.05).compute_gradients(cross_entropy, var_list=[W1, b1, W2, b2])

...
# somewhere in a for loop
_ = sess.run([tgv], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

As an example, if I print tgv[0], I get:

```py
Tensor("gradients_12/MatMul_24_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0", shape=(2, 80), dtype=float32)
```

**My Problem**

How can I extract the value of that gradient to numpy array? If I try to simply run `eval(session=sess)` I get:

```py
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_24' with dtype float and shape [?,2]
```

Comment: Can you please add full code?

Comment: I think you are getting above error because you are not feeding values to placeholders

Comment: @AnubhavSingh IIf I feed gradients, it works. However, wouldn't just running "compute_gradient()" calculate the gradients? I must be missing something

Comment: @AnubhavSingh Am I not feeding data in sess.run([tgv], feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y}) ? I thought that would take care of the feeding

Answer (score 0):

Look at @tf.custom_gradient for writing your own gradient calculation function.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient

If you're using eager execution, you can monitor the gradients using Gradient Tape.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape